# Matching explicitly instantiated function template with conversion

Tags: c++, function, templates, overloading, implicit-conversion

Consider this template with an implicit constructor

```
template<typename T>
struct X { X(T) { } };
```

and this function template

```
template<typename T>
void func(X<T>) { }
```

Even if I make an explicit instantiation of `func<T>()` for `T = int`

```
template void func<int>(X<int>);
```

A call to `func` like this doesn't compile

```
func(1);
```

Error:

> no matching function call for 'func'

I know template argument deduction doesn't work well with  conversions but in this case I create an explicit instantiation of `func` so there is no need for deduction and I expect conversions to work as with normal functions.

Why is not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is given `func(1);`, [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) fails to deduce `T` (as `int`).

> In order to instantiate a function template, every template argument must be known

but

> Type deduction does not consider implicit conversions (other than type adjustments listed above): that's the job for overload resolution, which happens later.

The explicit instantiation changes nothing; template argument deduction can't deduce `T`, then no instantiation (of `func<int>` or something else) would happen.

You can specify the template argument explicitly to bypass the template argument deduction.

```
func<int>(1);
```

You might write a wrapper for it like

```
template<typename T>
void bar(T t) {
    func<T>(t);
}
```

then you can

```
bar(1);
```